# Как работает import в Python

Tags: python, память, производительность, импорт, модули

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть такая ситуация:
у меня два Python файла. Каждый файл - это отдельный тест (занимаюсь автоматизацией для собственного развития).
Если я в каждый файл импортирую скажем модуль time, то как это отразится на скорости выполнения тестов?

То есть вопрос: если мы импортируем один и тот же модуль в два разных файла, интерпретатор сначала открывает первый файл, в нем уже есть import time, он его читает и что потом? Закидывает в оперативку? Потом он заканчивает тест и открывает следующий файл, а там снова import time. Интерпретатор уже его не читает, правильно? Этот модуль time уже есть в оперативной памяти? Или же интерпретатору приходится заново читать весь модуль time, исполнять в нем код, а старый модуль time он уже выгрузил из оперативки, когда закончился предыдущий тест и закрылся предыдущий файл?

Буду благодарен за ответ!!!
Всем заранее спасибо

Comment: «Этот модуль time уже есть в оперативной памяти?» — да

Comment: то есть если у меня будет 100 файлов и в каждый я импортирую модуль time, он просто будет браться из оперативной памяти?

Comment: «просто будет браться из оперативной памяти»

Comment: спасибо вам большое!)

Comment: Да, он там как-то проверяет, загружен ли уже модуль и второй раз не грузит уже. И делает он это по словарю, это вроде быстро.